# Android Actionbar SearchView with item.getItemId() not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, searchview

i'm developing an application with API 8. now i'm trying to add 3 items in my menu, one
of item i added is SearchView, i used `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` ofcourse to support the API 8,
and in my MainActivity  class in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` i'm trying to handle the click on searchView, but it is no longer working.
how can fix this?

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--My SearchView--->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/stringSearch"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_magnify"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <!--My Filter--->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:title="@string/StringFilter"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <!--Some menu--->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dots"
        android:title="@string/Settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        //I setup the searchView here
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        ....
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_search:
                //This is click event on searchView but unfortunately not working
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SearcView",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Menu Settings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_filter:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Menu Filter",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

So, as you can see in my code, i try to fire a toast when the menu item is clicked, everything is working but not my SearchView.
this is happen when i started to add `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` on menu in searchView item.
anyone can help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use one of the listeners on the SearchView class. The [OnSearchClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html#setOnSearchClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) looks like it may be the right fit for you.

Edit. Here's a code example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Handle clicks
            }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: any specific example for this? how can i implement `OnSearchClickListener` base on my code? im just new here. lock on idea.